# Custom Columns for Custom Post Type Manager

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, columns, table, post-editor

Failing miserably at adding a custom column

```
add_action('manage_edit-pricing_columns', 'manage_pricing_columns');
add_action('manage_pricing_posts_custom_column', 'manage_pricing_custom_columns');
function manage_pricing_columns($_columns) {
    $new_columns['cb'] = '<input type="checkbox" />';
    $new_columns['title'] = _x('Pricing Item', 'column name');
    $new_columns['categories'] = _x('Type', 'column name');
    $new_columns['date'] = _x('Created', 'column name');
    return $new_columns;
}
function manage_pricing_custom_columns($column, $post_id){
    global $post;
    switch($_columns) {
        case 'categories':
            $pt = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'pricing_type' );
            echo $pt[0]->name;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

`Type` column only ever shows `--`   Yes, I have verified `$pt[0]->name` `var_dumps` what it actually should be.

So, what am I doing wrong here?  I need the `Type` column to show my `pricing_type` value.

`pricing` is a custom post type, while `pricing_type` is a custom taxonomy of the `pricing` post type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action('manage_edit-pricing_columns', 'manage_pricing_columns');
add_action('manage_pricing_posts_custom_column', 'manage_pricing_custom_columns');
function manage_pricing_columns($_columns) {
    $new_columns['cb'] = '<input type="checkbox" />';
    $new_columns['title'] = _x('Pricing Item', 'wp');
    $new_columns['categories'] = _x('Type', 'wp');
    $new_columns['date'] = _x('Created', 'wp');
    return $new_columns;
}
function manage_pricing_custom_columns($column, $post_id){
    global $post;
    switch($_columns) {
        case 'pricing_type':
            $pt = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'pricing_type' );
            echo $pt[0]->name;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
add_action('manage_edit-pricing_columns', 'manage_pricing_columns');
add_action('manage_pricing_posts_custom_column', 'manage_pricing_custom_columns');
function manage_pricing_columns($_columns) {
    $new_columns['cb'] = '<input type="checkbox" />';
    $new_columns['title'] = _x('Pricing Item', 'column name');
    $new_columns['pricing_type'] = _x('Type', 'column name');
    $new_columns['date'] = _x('Created', 'column name');
    return $new_columns;
}
function manage_pricing_custom_columns($column){
    global $post;
    switch($column) {
        case 'pricing_type':
            $pt = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'pricing_type' );
            echo $pt[0]->name;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```